# What iPhone APIs are available for internet-based matchmaking games?

Tags: iphone

I have a pretty basic challenge-based iPhone game, and I wanted to know what my options are for player discovery & matchmaking. I may end up rolling my own server, but if I don't have to, even better.

So far, I've found [OpenFeint](http://openfeint.com) and [Scoreloop](http://scoreloop.com), but I don't really care about the social part or discovering other games, I just want a simple system with matchmaking, win/loss, and global rankings. [CocosLive](http://www.cocoslive.net/) has the global ranking part, but not the matchmaking.

Also just found [RakNet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/index.html).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) for a free to cheap alternative to setting up your own server.  It also has the added benefit of being Google, which to me spells reliability.

I expect that RakNet and similar companies will want a bunch of money for this solution - one of their clients is Sony Online Entertainment which to me spells money.

Also as you search around for solutions I would focus more on searching for open source code to put on your Google App Engine rather than a service.  Online services require bandwith, which costs money.  Information is free.

Good luck!